# Comparing objects and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, comparison, operator-overloading

In my program I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Base // Base is an abstract class
{
};

class A : public Base
{
};

class B : public Base
{
};
```

I would like to do the following:

```
foo(const Base& one, const Base& two)
{
  if (one == two)
  {
    // Do something
  } else
  {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

I have issues regarding the `operator==()` here. Of course comparing an instance `A` and an instance of `B` makes no sense but comparing two instances of `Base` should be possible. (You can't compare a Dog and a Cat however you can compare two Animals)

I would like the following results:

> `A == B` **=>** `false`
>
> `A == A` **=>** `true` or `false`, depending on the effective value of the two instances
>
> `B == B` **=>** `true` or `false`, depending on the effective value of the two instances

#### My question is: is this a good design/idea ? Is this even possible ? What functions should I write/overload ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Base // Base is an abstract class
{
    virtual bool equals(const Base& b) = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
    virtual bool equals(const Base& base)
    {
        if (const A* a = dynamic_cast<const A*>(&base))
        {
            // Return true iff this and a are equal.
        }
        return false;
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
    virtual bool equals(const Base& base)
    {
        if (const B* b = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&base))
        {
            // Return true iff this and b are equal.
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think about this... Thank you. I'll never code again when I'm sick.

Answer (score 1):

Overload the operator at the base: subclasses references will be casted to the base class reference.

Can't see any problem with the design - not without more context.

Comment: Well the issue is that the `Base` class contains *no information or logic*. And If I use `dynamic_cast<>` in `Base::operator==()`  I have to consider every possibility, which is not possible.

Comment: So Base, rather than being an "abstract" class, is an "interface". If it's an interface - that is, you only have pure virtual methods - then operator== doesn't make any sense at all. What are you going to compare if Base objects do not have any state?

Answer (score 0):

I can not craft a counterexample right now, but as far as I remember, the comparison operator (as something transitive, reflexive and symmetric) will *always* break (and be a source of malicious errors) when combined with inheritance. Possible it will not break you app, your use case, just half a year later when you subclass your subclass...